# Package com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage does not exist

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-storage, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android Studio (v0.5.4) to build an app. While I understand that this is a beta IDE it has worked just fine for me up until now. I am getting an error that I cannot get past.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':gavi:compileDebugJava'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   Error:(9, 47) error: package com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage does not exist
>   Error:(49, 9) error: cannot find symbol class GcsService

my gradle file looks like this

> compile files('libs/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.9.jar',)
>   compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.17.0-rc.jar',)
>   compile files('libs/google-api-services-storage-v1beta2-rev42-1.17.0-rc.jar',)
>   
>   
>    This is the line that is causing the error :
>   GcsService service = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
>   
>   
>   I have a folder called 'libs' and the corresponding jar file are in there.
>   What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would try this compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar') instead. It will grab all the jars you have in libs and include them. I am hoping you don't have any jars you don't want to include. I am also hoping this will solve your problem since I'm hoping you spelled something wrong since google-api-services-storage-v1beta2-rev42-1.17.0-rc.jar' is a mouthful :).

Are you using proguard by any chance?  If so I would recommend turning that off, or try adding a specific rule.

Comment: I tried the Gradle changes suggested and I still get the same error . Pro guard only had an entry for release and is set to false anyway so I doubt that's the issue. Any other suggestions?

Comment: ended up removing the culprit and adding a backend to my app through the Android Studio menu. This solved the issue as all the necessary dependencies were added/ resolved for me.